# Workaround a null value when I delete an item in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, null, conditional-rendering

When I delete an item in my react component, some code in another component turns null and the react application crashes. Is there any workaround to this or any way I could implement this way instead of getting an error? Please see the code below.

When I delete an item in a component, some external code renders to null I guess, because I am getting the error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

```
  114 | class AccountActivity extends Component {
  115 |   static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  116 |     const { currentAccountId, accounts } = props;
> 117 |     const currentAccountType = currentAccountId ? accounts.filter(acc => acc.id === currentAccountId)[0].type : null;
  118 | 
  119 |     const { currentTab } = state;
  120 |     if (currentAccountType === ACCOUNT_TYPES.MANUAL && (currentTab === ACTIVITY_TABS.OPEN_ORDERS || currentTab === ACTIVITY_TABS.ORDER_HISTORY)) {
```

Comment: The best solution is to remove the item from the `accounts` list rather than setting it to null.

Comment: That error means that there is no value at `accounts.filter(...)[0]`. Try `accounts.filter(...)[0]?.type`. The question mark indicates to javascript that the preceding value may be null or undefined and to stop executing the statement if it is.

Comment: @CharlesBamford Thanks for your input, however I have tried that and gotten an unexpected token error when I did that

Comment: Okay, I don't know what version of js you're running. You can mimic that behavior with: `let currentAccountType = null; if (currentAccountId) {const filtered = accounts.filter(acc => acc.id === currentAccountId); currentAccountType = filtered.length && filtered[0].type;}`

Comment: @CharlesBamford Thanks Charles, that seems to have done the trick. However, there is another area where im getting null, and have tried using the same method. But returning some error here:

   const accountType = filterAccountId ? accounts.find(acc => acc.id === filterAccountId).type : null;